# Detecting unicode private use area characters with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

What is the proper way to identify unicode private use characters in python 3? There's nothing obviously relevant in the module `unicodedata`, which which makes it easy to look up character names and attributes.

Some background: `unicodedata.name()`, which gives the name of unicode characters, will raise a `ValueError` if called with a private use character (e.g., try `unicodedata.name("\uf026")`). But whitespace characters (except for space itself), and possibly other things, also trigger an exception. So what's a non-hacky, reliable way to detect PUA characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Private use characters are all in the `Co` [general category](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values), as returned by `category()` in `unicodedata`:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> def is_pua(c):
...   return unicodedata.category(c) == 'Co'
...
>>> is_pua(u'\uF026')
True
```

Given that the Unicode Standard [guarantees](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#pua4) that the set of private use characters will *never* change (no characters will ever be added or removed), it's also safe to hard-code the [three ranges](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#pua2):

- `U+E000` to `U+F8FF`
- `U+F0000` to `U+FFFFD`
- `U+100000` to `U+10FFFD`

Comment: Makes sense. But there's really no library method that already does this simple calculation? (e.g., in the form of a character class)

Comment: I forgot that they're also in the same `category()`, which is probably a little cleaner.

Comment: Hmm, I already tried `category()`, but the meaning of the two-letter codes (`Co` for the codepoint I tried) doesn't seem to be documented within `unicodedata` . Is it a given that only PUA characters have category `Co`? That would indeed be a good solution.

Comment: Found it myself: Googling was no help, but python's [unicode howto](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/unicode.html) has a pointer to a table of [General Category Values](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values). Category `Co` seems to be for PUA codepoints only. (You are welcome to include this in your answer).