# Removing all invalid characters (e.g. \uf0b7) from text

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, nlp, data-cleaning

I currently have several text coming in which sometimes contains the character 'invalid character' e.g. \uf0b7 or \uf077. I don't have a way of knowing which of the invalid character codes a specific text might contain and I wondered if there was a way to make sure that a string is cleaned of all types of 'invalid character', since a process later on (which is dependent on a third party package) can not receive a string which contains it.

I've tried searching for a solution, but all I get it is answers regarding regular characters which people want removed (e.g. '^%$&*') which they have classified as invalid characters, however I want to remove/replace the actual character 'invalid character' in all its forms

Comment: Please, clarify what *several text coming* means. Where does your text come from?

Comment: Have you tried using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html)?

Comment: Are you reading in a suitable encoding i.e 'utf8' ?

Comment: I have tried using regex, but I have not found a solution yet that is a catch all for all different 'invalid character' codes. Which I would love to know if anyone knows how to.

Comment: @AkashBasudevan yes I am reading in suitable encoding (utf8), but the text I receive sometimes contains the invalid character

Comment: @sentence they come from a pdf extracted with tika

Comment: Then, are you talking about removing invalid characters from a string?

Comment: @sentence Yes all characters classified as 'invalid character' such as \uf0b7 or \uf077

Comment: Found the solution. My problem were the Private Use Area Block 'invalid character' codes. Since they run from \ue000 until \uf8ff I now has a catch all I can use for regex.

Comment: They are not invalid; They are private use. A user has put value into the text. Are you sure you want to toss them? What would it do to the meaning and formatting?

Answer (score 0):

The Python library codecs might be of help.  Take a look at the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.htm

In my use case, I was doing some analysis of documents that had non-ASCII text.  For my purposes, ignoring the invalid characters was acceptable.  I opened the files with the following line and was able to parse the corpus.

```
for filename in os.listdir(ROOT_DIR):
    with codecs.open(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, filename), encoding = 'UTF8', errors ='replace' ) as f:
```

Comment: I tried it, but I don't seem to get it to work, since the text has already been decoded (it comes from pdf with text extraced with tika) at this point and I can't seem to remove the 'invalid character' which sometimes are present in a text extracted from a bad pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. [It turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540152/detecting-unicode-private-use-area-characters-with-python/32540287#32540287) private use areas characters are in the `Co` [general category](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values), as returned by `category()` in `unicodedata`.

I fixed my problem as follow:

```
import unicodedata

def is_pua(c):
    return unicodedata.category(c) == 'Co'

content = "This\uf0b7 is a \uf0b7string \uf0c7with private \uf0b7use are\uf0a7as blocks\uf0d7." 

"".join([char for char in content if not is_pua(char)])
```

This outputs:

```
'This is a string with private use areas blocks.'
```

Comment: ``r'\\u[e-f][0-9a-z]{3}'`` are not the unicode points above ``\ue000``. They are *literally* the characters ``\``, ``u``, and so on.

Comment: Could you please share what would be the appropriate regex ?

Comment: You should ask a separate question for that, provided there isn't one already. [Using answers-as-questions can lead to deletion.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)