# Converted bytes to string then unable to print string

Tags: python, string, byte

I struggled to convert bytes from a PDF to a string. When I run the code, it says it converted to class `str`, but when I try to print it, I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\uf0b7' in position 432: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've tried the "decode" function with a dozen settings, it doesn't work without "ignore" or "reversebackslash" after the unicode transformation format.

I'd like to be able to print and use the string, but ultimately, I want to count the number of occurrences of keywords in the PDF. Is there a better way to do this that does not involve converting to a string?

```python
def pdf_to_text(path):
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = BytesIO()
    layout = LAParams(all_texts=True)
    device = TextConverter(manager, retstr, laparams=layout)
    filepath = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, device)

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(filepath, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue().lower()
    filepath.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    text_str = text.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    print(type(text_str))
    print(text_str)
    return text
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched it on google and I have found that this '\uf0b7' char is an printatl char.
I believe that you can print the text from the PDF without this char, because it is part of the PDF protocol. Therefore, if you remove this char it maybe help you.
Try this site: [Removing all invalid characters (e.g. \uf0b7) from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337705/removing-all-invalid-characters-e-g-uf0b7-from-text)