# Detect / replace utf characters

Tags: python, text, utf-8, nlp

I want to detect and/or replace weird utf, non-emoji characters that break my tokenization pipeline, like `\uf0fc`, which renders like a cup/glass:
[image: Rendering]

That image / code is not contained in the [emojis package](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/), which I tried for filtering.

Is there a class that describes all such characters?
Is there a way I can reliably detect them?

Comment: It depends on what you mean "non-emoji character that break **my** tokenization. Unicode characters are classed in classes, "old emoji" are symbols (but so many math symbols). Note: some fonts/OS will replace old emoji (so black and white) into a more modern emoji view

Comment: The part which requests a library recommendation makes this off-topic, but the more fundamental problem with this question is that it is unclear what exactly you want to achieve and what you already tried.  We have no idea what your tokenization pipeline looks like or what will or will not break it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a character from a [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas). It happens to look like a tankard in your font, but the Unicode standard doesn't mandate a specific look or meaning for these; it has whatever meaning you assign to it. The idea is that you agree upon a meaning with whoever you're communicating with - privately, meaning without getting the Unicode Consortium involved.

You can use the standard `unicodedata` module to check whether a character is from the `Co` category, or just hardcode the ranges, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540152).